# Query outputting YouTube url rather than embedded video

Tags: wp-query

I am having an issue with a query outputting the YouTube url rather than the video itself.
The post I am querying has a Youtube url in the content area. Of course, when viewing the post, you don’t see the url, you see the video, as it’s supposed to be.

When using get_the_content to display this post on another page, it’s outputting the Youtube url rather than embedding the video automatically. If I use the_content, then it outputs the video, but it does so before the other html.

Here’s my query, if that helps: http://pastebin.com/zUHXSjui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that as you are calling the function directly, there are filters that arent being called, you can fix this by calling the `apply_filters` function using `the_content` filter, like this.

```
apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
```

Where `$content` is the result of `get_the_content()`